# How is this Checksum calculated?

Tags: c++, qt, io, serial-port

Good day friends.
I'm using Qt C++ and I've ran into a issue calculating a checksum for a serial communication protocol. I'm very new to serial programming and this is a little above my knowledge atm
Per their documentation.

```
Communication format

Head  Address    CID   Datalength Data Check    Tail

0x7E  0x01~0x0e  0x01  -          -    checksum 0x0D
```

the head never changes, the address can change, the CID is a command
I don't understand how the data length is to be calculated
the checksum I'm not clear on how they calculate it. Are they taking the first 5 bytes then calculating the checksum then adding the tail ? or only the "command" which to me is the CID byte. but that doesn't make sense.

The function they use to calculate the checksum

```
byte check(byte* buf, byte len)
{
    byte i, chk= 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        chk ^= buf[i];
        sum += buf[i];
    }
    return ((chk^sum)&0xFF);
}
```

Which I Wrote in Qt as

```
unsigned char MainWindow::Checksum_Check(char* buf, char len)
{
    unsigned char i, chk = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        chk ^= buf[i];
        sum += buf[i];
    }
    return ((chk^sum)&0xFF);
}
```

So sending a hexidecimal command using QBytearray

```
 QByteArray Chunk("\x7E\x01\x01\x00");

    char *TestStr = Chunk.data();
    unsigned char Checksum = Checksum_Check(TestStr, Chunk.length()); // tried sizeof(char) even tried sizeof(Chunk.size())

    const char cart[] = {'\x7E', '\x01', '\x01', '\x00', checksum, '\x0D'};
    QByteArray ba4(QByteArray::fromRawData(cart, 6));
    SerialPort->write(ba4.toHex()); // Tried write(ba4); as well. 
    SerialPort->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
```

What i get in qDebug() is
Checksum  "FE"
Command   "7E010100FE0D"

Which looks correct but the device ignores the request.
My question is. Is the checksum calculated correctly by me or am I missing something crucial ?
Any advice or help would be most welcome as I am stuck.

Ive checked it with one of their example commands:

```
7E 01 F2 02 FF FF FE 0D
```

which if i do this:

```
QByteArray Chunk("\x7E\x01\xF2\x02\xFF\xFF");

char *TestStr = Chunk.data();
unsigned char Checksum = Checksum_Check(TestStr, Chunk.length());

const char cart[] = {'\x7E', '\x01', '\xF2', '\x02','\xFF', '\xFF', Checksum, '\x0D'};
QByteArray ba4(QByteArray::fromRawData(cart, 8));

QString hexvalue;
hexvalue = QString("%1").arg(CRC, 0, 16, QLatin1Char( '0' ));

qDebug() << "Checksum " << hexvalue.toUpper();
qDebug() << "Command  " << ba4.toHex().toUpper();

SerialPort->write(ba4.toHex());
```

Gives me

```
Checksum  "FE"
Command   "7E01F202FFFFFE0D"
```

which is correct. By the looks of things. But the device still doesn't respond
So I just wanna verify that the checksum is in fact generated correctly.

Also in the documentation is an example

```
PC software Command:
buf[0] = 0x7E; //head
buf[1] = 0x01; //addr
buf[2] = 0x01; //CID
buf[3] = 0x00; //data length
buf[4] = CHK;  //Check code
buf[5] = 0x0D; //tail
```

And here is another question. How can a checksum buf[4] be generated while the ByteArray is still being constructed. It doesn't make sense to me at this point. I dont know/understand which bytes they use for the checksum

Anyone? thanks

Comment: If a checksum is required, its specification should be described in the document of the communication target device. There is no standard that can be applied to any device without specification. If the document does not have a specification, please contact the device vendor.

Comment: Thank you, Ive already fire off 4 emails to the vendor.

Comment: *"one of their example commands ... But the device still doesn't respond"* -- If that is an example provided by the vendor, then you seem to also have a fundamental problem of communicating with the device.  *"How can a checksum buf[4] be generated while the ByteArray is still being constructed"* -- Constant values at fixed positions in the message (such as the `Head` and `Tail`) do not contribute to verifying the data integrity of the message using a checksum because before you can perform a checksum or CRC, you would have validated the start and end of the message.

Comment: I got some progress made last night late. The address 0x01 after head as per documentation was one issue. Setting it to 0x00 the device started responding. So it looks like the checksum wasn't the issue. Only the address targeted. In the documentation 0x00 is reserved however 0x01 to 0x0e should be the scope. But I found this is not the case